# php mysqli function not working

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I have created a function that is not returning any values:

```
$j2_2=  mysqli_query($con, "select * from Hagrala where Ale = 7 order by Mispar desc limit 1;");
        $j2_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($j2_2);
        $spade_7_2=$j2_3['Mispar'];
```

This works

```
$v='9';  
$j2_2=  mysqli_query($con, "select * from Hagrala where Ale = $v order by Mispar desc limit 1;");
        $j2_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($j2_2);
        $spade_9_2=$j2_3['Mispar'];
```

This also works
but with the function foo it doesn't work:

```
function foo($arg_1)    

 {    
      $t_1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from Hagrala where Ale = $arg_1 order by Mispar desc limit 1;");
      $t_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($t_1);
     return $t_2;  
 }      

 $spade_10_2=foo('10');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$con` is not available to your function because of scope. `$con` is in the global scope and is not available to your function unless you make it so by available means. The best way to do this is to pass it as a parameter to the function.

```
function foo($arg_1, $con) {    
     $t_1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from Hagrala where Ale = $arg_1 order by Mispar desc limit 1;");
     $t_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($t_1);
     return $t_2;  
}      
$spade_10_2=foo('10', $con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$con` in the function parameter to get access of it with in a function.

```
function foo($arg_1,$con)    

 {    
      $t_1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from Hagrala where Ale = $arg_1 order by Mispar desc limit 1;");
      $t_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($t_1);
     return $t_2;  
 }      

 $spade_10_2=foo('10');
```

Comment: @DanielBen-Shabtay, If it is suitable for you.Please mark it so that it will be useful for others also.